# is there an R package that allows to maximize a linear objective with a non-linear constraint?

Tags: r, optimization

I've been able to minimize a non-linear objective with a linear constraint using `quadprog`, however, I haven't been able to do it the other way around...

```
require(quadprog)
min_var <- function(Obj,Rentabilidades,var_covar){

  b <- c(Obj,1)
  Betha <- var_covar
  A <- t(matrix(rbind(Rentabilidades,c(1,1)),nrow=2))
  Gamma <- matrix(0,nrow=2)
  solve.QP(Betha,Gamma,A,b,2)

}
```

Now I want to maximize what previously was the constraint taking as a new constraint the former objective. Regrettably, `solve.QP()` only supports linear constraints. Does anyone know a package similar to `quadprog` that might help me?

Comment: I'm guessing you are unaware of the requirement that you search before posting questions. I'm also guessing that you are unaware of the existence of CRAN Task Views, in particular: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

A standard portfolio optimization model looks like:

```
min sum((i,j), x(i)*Q(i,j)*x(j))
sum(i,x(i)) = 1
sum(i,r(i)*x(i)) >= R
x(i) >= 0
```

This is a Quadratic Programming model, and can be solved with standard QP solvers.

If you turn this around (maximize return subject to a risk constraint), you can write:

```
max sum(i,r(i)*x(i))
sum((i,j), x(i)*Q(i,j)*x(j)) <= V
sum(i,x(i)) = 1
x(i) >= 0
```

This is now a Quadratically Constrained problem. Luckily this is convex so you can use solvers like Cplex, Gurobi, or Mosek to solve them (they have R interfaces). An open source candidate could be a solver like ECOSolveR, or even better a framework like cxvr.